# react-i18next react-redux and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, i18next

So... I have to do a redux connect of a i18n translated component using TypeScript. The problem is that the types are going crazy!

```
interface Props extends InjectedTranslateProps {
  page: number;
}

interface StoreData {
  count: number;
}

const BookComponent = ({ page, count }: Props & StoreData) => {
...
}


const translatedComponent = translate(['books'])(BookComponent );

function mapStateToProps(state: Store): StoreData {
  return {
    count: state.count
  };
}

export default connect<StoreData, void, Props>(mapStateToProps)(translatedComponent);
```

It doesn't want to work at all and I get this error:

```
Argument of type 'ComponentClass<Pick<Props & InjectedTranslateProps, "page"> & TranslateHocProps>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<StoreData & DispatchProp<any> & Props>'.

Type 'ComponentClass<Pick<Props & InjectedTranslateProps, "page"> & TranslateHocProps>' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<StoreData & DispatchProp<any> & Props>'.

Type 'ComponentClass<Pick<Props & InjectedTranslateProps, "page"> & TranslateHocProps>' provides no match for the signature '(props: StoreData & DispatchProp<any> & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any> | null'.

const translatedForm: React.ComponentClass<Pick<Props & InjectedTranslateProps, "page"> & TranslateHocProps>
```

But if I change Props to any, the problem disappears.

```
export default connect<StoreData, void, any>(mapStateToProps)(translatedComponent);
```